# Passing class as argument to a method

Tags: java

I'm doing the following to establish the public methods of the class TestA.

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
Method[] methods = TestA.class.getDeclaredMethods();
for(Method method : methods) 
{
  if(Modifier.isPublic(method.getModifiers())) 
  {         
    strings.add(method.getName());
  }
}
```

I also need to do the same thing for `TestB`, `TestC` etc so I'd like to have a function which takes a class name and returns a String array of the public methods. How can I do this?

If I have an Object parameter, I will have to create an instance of each Class before I send them to the function. I wish to avoid this.

Comment: FYI you can have a [`Class`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) as a parameter to a method.

Comment: You can pass a `java.lang.Class` object as a parameter to the method.

Comment: Do you need the public methods from your class' superclass too?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you want:

```
public static List<String> getPublicDeclaredMethods(Class<?> clazz) {
    List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
    Method[] methods = clazz.getDeclaredMethods();
    for(Method method : methods)  {
        if(Modifier.isPublic(method.getModifiers())) {
            strings.add(method.getName());
        }
    }
    return strings;
}
```

Then call it with:

```
List<String> names = getPublicDeclaredMethods(TestA.class);
```

You should also consider using [`Class.getMethods`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethods%28%29) which only returns public methods anyway - but returns ones inherited from superclasses.

Comment: Do you think `<?>` is necessary? I guess we can omit it and can just write `Class`. Does it makes any difference?

Comment: @HarryJoy: Yes - `Class` is a raw type, which will cause compile-time warnings. `Class<?>` is a generic type using a wildcard, which is fine without any warnings.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `java.lang.Class` instance it self , like shown below

```
 public void introspectClass(Class cls){
    List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
    Method[] methods = cls.getDeclaredMethods();
    for(Method method : methods) 
    {
      if(Modifier.isPublic(method.getModifiers())) 
      {         
        strings.add(method.getName());
      }
    }
    }
```